# "android.view.InflateException: Binary XM file line" when changing activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, inflate-exception

I am currently developing an Android app and having issues when implementing the code which directs the user from one activity to the other. 
The Android Studio IDE does not show error in any Java or XML code but when the activity is launched and I try to switch for the activity "Sign In" the program will fail and the log will produce the following error

```
> 05-12 18:42:57.687 32378-32378/com.cars.evd.dealership
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.cars.evd.dealership, PID: 32378
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cars.evd.dealership/com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML
> file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>         at com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:25)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
>         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
>         at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
>         at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>         at com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:25) 
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) 
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Manifest**

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".SignIn">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>     </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> </application> 
> </manifest>
> ```

**MainActivity.Java**

> ```
> Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
> TextView txtSlogan;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
>     btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
>
>     txtSlogan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
>     Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NABILA.TTF");
>     txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);
>
>
>     btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             Intent SignUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
>             startActivity(SignUp);
>         }
>     });
>
>     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             Intent SignIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
>             startActivity(SignIn);
>         }
>     });
>
> } }
> ```

**activity_main.xml**

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_width="200dp"
>         android:layout_height="200dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/logo" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
>         android:layout_width="200dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/slogan"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:weightSum="2"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="8dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:background="@color/btnSignActive"
>         android:text="@string/SignUp"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>        />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="8dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:background="@color/btnSignActive"
>         android:text="@string/SignIn"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>        />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**SignIn.Java**

> ```
> public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
> EditText edtemail, edtPassword;
> Button btnSignIn; 
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
>
>     edtPassword = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
>     edtemail = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
>     btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
>
>
>     //Init Firebase
>     final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
>     final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
>
>     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
>             mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
>             mDialog.show();
>
>             table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>                     //check if user not exist in database
>                     if(dataSnapshot.child(edtemail.getText().toString()).exists()) {
>                         //get user information
>                         mDialog.dismiss();
>                         User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtemail.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
>                         assert user != null;
>                         user.setName(edtemail.getText().toString());
>                         if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
>                         } else {
>                             Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong Password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                         }
>                     }else{
>                         Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exist in Database !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     });
>
> } }
> ```

**SignIn.xml**

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
>         android:id="@+id/edtemail"
>         android:hint="@string/name_of_e_mail"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
>         android:text="@string/daniel25_gmail_com"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="34sp"
>         android:inputType="phone"
>         app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
>         app:met_maxCharacters="11"
>         app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
>         />
>
>     <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
>         android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
>         android:hint="@string/password"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
>         android:text="@string/_1234"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="34sp"
>         android:inputType="textPassword"
>         app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
>         app:met_maxCharacters="11"
>         app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
>         />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>     android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
>     android:text="@string/SignIn"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="8dp"
>     app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
>     app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
>     app:shadowEnabled="true"
>     app:shadowHeight="5dp"
>     app:cornerRadius="4dp"
>     /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

I have been trying to figure out for a month to know why the error shows up but to no good.

Comment: Can't convert value at index 1 to color . Check your color.xml . Or check color code in layout if you have used hardcoded color codes .

Comment: Here are the colors .
Checked the files and none of them come up as hardcoded at least according to the IDE in both XML pages.

<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#004d40</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00251a</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#39796b</color>

    <color name="btnSignUp">#39796b</color>
    <color name="btnSignActive">#A9d440</color>
</resources>

Comment: See https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41 .

Comment: That is correct, it seems that my problem was really the deprecation of the FButton that I was using on my own current SDK, finally fixed.

Thank you for the answer :)